# Alon.cls incompatibility with hyperref – workarounds?

Tags: hyperref, pandoc

I'm writing a book with CRC publishing who gave me their proprietary `Alon.cls` class file[^1]; unfortunately, its documentation warns of incompatibility with `hyperref` without giving more details, and indeed I'm getting errors when I try to use it with pandoc-generated LaTeX (I'm writing the book in Quarto, which lets me produce e-book, website, etc. from the same input).

Is there a good/easy way to provide dummy replacements for hyperref's macros such as

```
\hypertarget{intro}{%
\section*{Introduction}\label{intro}}
```

or any other workaround when one is forced to use such a class?

[1]: Apparently someone posted a copy of `Alon.cls` in their public gitee repo

Comment: you could link to the class. from your fragment the only hyperref command is `\hypertarget` which you could define as `\newcommand\hypertarget[2]{#2}` or (better) just delete from your source, but if you do not show the class, or a document or any error messages from hyperref, it is not possible to help

Comment: I believe the class is not meant to be shared, unfortunately. That being said, someone (not me) put it [here on their public repo](https://gitee.com/mirrors_bmcfee/dstbook/blob/main/Alon.cls). I cannot remove these commands from the source (not easily, at least), because they're introduced by pandoc when converting from markdown. I'll try the newcommand you gave, I tried it as a single-argument macro and that didn't work.

Comment: you need to at least say what error you got, or if it's a private code ask the publisher for support. There is no point asking on a public forum for help on an unspecified error in unseen secret code

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Defining a few dummy macros seems to do the trick, thanks. I was kind of stuck to be honest, between CRC's proprietary mess, and pandoc's expectations that hyperref be included.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David's comments I'm now using defining these dummy macros as a workaround:

```
\newcommand\hypertarget[2]{#2}
\newcommand\texorpdfstring[2]{#1}
\newcommand\bookmarksetup[1]{}
\newcommand\href[1]{#1}
```

This seems to cover the macros introduced by pandoc relying on bookmark and hyperref.

Hopefully someday CRC will fix the mess they've made in that Alon.cls class.

Comment: do you mind sharing a minimal example of your successful Quarto setup (without the Alon.cls class itself)?